# Localizing activerecord model name in error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization

I have a Query class for which I would like its human_readable name to be 'Search' in active record error messages. How does the activerecord localization tree look for this case?

I tried:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      query: "Search"
    errors:
      models:
        query:
          attributes:
            name: 
              unique_within_scope: "blah blah"
```

and the attribute stuff works via:

```
errors.add(:name, I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.query.attributes.name.unique_within_scope'))
```

in the model. But I was hoping the translation of the error message for unique_within_scope would result in:

"Search save failed:
blah blah"

instead of:

"Query save failed:
blah blah"

as it does now.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually worked, I had just needed to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

while your approach worked, this would be cleaner:

```
errors.add(:name, :unique_within_scope)
```

and then simply define a resource string

```
activerecord.errors.models.query.attributes.name.unique_within_scope
```

In other words, if you pass in a symbol, it assumes that it is a resource key, and will look it up in your resource bundle.

An additional benefit is that you could also define

```
activerecord.errors.messages.unique_within_scope
```

to set a default message for errors of this type (used by different models or different properties) which you can then override for specific models if necessary.